# NS Condition for all eigenvalues contained in the field F?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $T: V(F) \rightarrow V(F)$ is a linear transformation, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. What is the necessary and/or sufficient condition that $F$ contains all eigenvalues of the matrix (corresponding to the linear transformation $T$)?

Note: A is a real symmetric matrix, all its eigenvalues are real.

For rational symmetric matrices, are there any such classifications?
Means, if $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Q})$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$, then under what conditions $\lambda(A) \subset Q?$

Comment: The question is not about finding counter example. There are plenty such.

Comment: Is $F$ fixed? A sufficient condition (for $F$) is that $F$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @Berci: Thank you.